# Using key props causes issues while working with nextjs and redux toolkit when I try to change child component

Tags: next.js

In my `notes.tsx` file, I have written code for displaying `NoteItem` components using map function.

`NoteItem` component has the functionality to be edited and I am using redux toolkit, redux thunk and an backend API to handle that functionality.

When I use key prop in the `Notes.tsx`, I start getting errors when I try to edit the `NoteItem` on the frontend, and when I remove the map property it works fine but then I will not be able to deploy it on the vercel.

Can somebody please tell me why I am facing Issues while using `key` prop?

**Steps to reproduce the issue on deployed live application :**

1. Sign up and then login
2. create a new note
3. try to edit that note

You will start getting errors because `note.body` and `note.title` are treated as undefined.

Notes.tsx:

```
{notes
          ? notes.map((item: any) => {
              return <Noteitem key = {item._id} note={item} />;
            })
          : null}
```

Edit functionality in NoteItem.tsx:

```
  const handleEditConfirm = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editNote(note));
    setShowEditModal(false);
  };

/* some code for displaying NoteItem omitted*/
 <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleEditClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button
            disabled={note.title.length < 5 || note.body.length < 5}
            variant="primary"
            onClick={handleEditConfirm}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
```

Edit note functionality in notesSlice.tsx:

```
export const editNote = createAsyncThunk("editNote", async (note:any) =>{
    const response = await axios.put("api/notes/editNote",{id:note._id, title:note.title, body:note.body});
    const updatedNote:any = await response.data.note;
    // console.log(updatedNote)
    
    return {note: updatedNote};


})

  .addCase(editNote.fulfilled, (state, action) =>{
                // console.log(action.payload);      
                const id = action.payload.note._id;
                const newNotesData = (state.notesData as any)?.map((note : any) =>
                    note._id === id ? action.payload : note
                );
            
                console.log(newNotesData);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    notesData : newNotesData
                }
            })
```

backend API:

```
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/connect";
import { verifyJwtToken } from "@/lib/jwt";
import Note from "@/models/noteModel";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

connect();
export async function PUT(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const { id,title,body } = await request.json();
    const token =  cookies().get("token")!.value;
    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        status: 401,
        success: false,
        message: "Invalid auth-token",
      });
    }
    const userData: any = verifyJwtToken(token);

    const note = await Note.findById(id);
    if (!note) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        status: 500,
        success: false,
        message: "Note does not exist",
      });
    }
    
    if (note.user != userData.email) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        status: 500,
        success: false,
        message: "Invalid User",
      });
    }

   const updatedNote = await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{
      title,
      body
    });
    return NextResponse.json({
        note:updatedNote,
        status:200,
        success:true,
        message:"Note successfully updated"
    })

  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      success: false,
      error,
      error_message: "Was not able to delete the note",
    });
  }
}
```

deployed live application: https://notedly-nine.vercel.app/

Github source code: https://github.com/abhinav700/Notedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after more debugging.
in `notesSlice.tsx`

```
const newNotesData = (state.notesData as any)?.map((note : any) =>
                    note._id === id ? action.payload : note
                );
```

should be replaced by

```
const newNotesData = (state.notesData as any)?.map((note : any) =>
                    note._id === id ? action.payload.note : note
                );
```